# Process "winedevice.exe" delaying systemd shutdown

Tags: systemd, shutdown, wine, reboot

Almost every time I shutdown my PC I have to wait about a 2 minutes for:

```
A stop job is running for user manager for UID 1000
```

I know this is caused by the `winedevice.exe` process

Only way I found to solve it would be running:

```
kill -9 $(ps aux |grep -i '\.exe' |awk '{print $2}'|tr '\n' ' ')
```

But I would like this to be done automatically before shutting down or restarting

Or that systemd would kill the process instantly instead of waiting 2 minutes

I've tried in every way to create a service to do this but nothing works

I already reduced the time in `/etc/systemd/system.conf` but it doesn't work either...

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

```bash
cat $HOME/.config/systemd/user.conf

[Manager]
DefaultTimeoutStopSec=10s
```

Comment: Thanks a lot

That worked